# How do I move a tab in Notepad++ to a new window?

Tags: notepad++

How do I move a tab in Notepad++ to a new window? (EDIT: The `Move to New Instance` option is disabled, how do I enable it?)

I have tried dragging it out such as you do in Firefox and Chrome, but it doesn't work. I have also tried `Move to Other View` option, but it splits the same Notepad++ window into two.

Comment: right click tab > move to/open in new instance

Comment: that's it, but that option is greyed out for me, which must explain why i missed it. i'll append my question with this info.

Comment: It only works for files that have been saved (when the tab icon is not red)

Comment: This question is not strictly off topic for Stack Overflow; there's no need to move it.

Comment: @AlexK, add that in an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexK, once the file is saved, the drag and drop method also works.

Comment: this is not about programming and should be on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can right click the tab and select *move to* or *open in new instance*.

This only works for files that are not dirty (when the tab icon is not red).

Comment: Thank you. Just as a note to others, the drag and drop method also works once the file is not dirty. It's too bad it has this restriction though, as usually I'm messing around with file data that I don't wish to save.

Comment: Minor nitpick: when I've just created a new file and have not typed anything yet, the tab icon is blue, but it can't be moved to another instance. It has to be saved first.

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar: Thanks for this addition, I had no idea why it did not work for me - even though the icon was blue.

Comment: I would just like to clarify, "dirty" files meant files that are not yet saved?

Comment: Yep a dirty file is one that's been opened (or created) then edited but has not yet been saved.

Comment: A dirty file is also one where we did a 'find all in document' and have that pane open

Comment: Tab is 'dirty' also when it's newly opened, needs to be saved before moving to new instance.

Answer (score 34):

Right-click the tab you are working with, and click "Move to New Instance", or to open the file *again* in a new window, click "Open in New Instance."

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's the answer, but it's greyed out for me, explaining why I missed it. How do I enable it? I have appended my question with this info.

Comment: It's grey because you need to save the file first.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, gave it to AlexK as he answered the question in full for me first.

Answer (score 21):

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to create a new instance.
2. Drag the wanted tab into the new instance with the mouse.

Comment: This is the best option for starting out with a scratchpad file ... it's already in a new instance so no need to move it when it gets dirty.

Answer (score 11):

Simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Mouse click</kbd> to drag and drop the tab will create a new `Notepad++` window instance.

Also, make sure the tab is NOT in RED.

Answer (score 9):

If you would like to open each file on separate instance during initial open action itself, there is a setting.

Navigate to `settings -> Preference`

[image]

Comment: also wonder what do you use for the arts-and-crafts? (the 1 and 2 in your diagram).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using it for few years, never realized you can enhance it with those 'accents'. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this out and thought it might help people, you can also create a new instance of Notepad++ via "Run --> Open in New Instance" on the toolbar. The default hotkey is alt + F6.